# ScrollView and LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to get a quite simple layout in Android, but I just can't get it to work. All I want is a header (by `include` an XML file), followed by a `ScrollView` to show a large body of text, and two buttons in the bottom, that should always be visible.

I have fiddled with `LinearLayout`s and `RelativeLayout`s, but somehow, I can't get it to work. What I have until now is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/header" />


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/svDisclaimer"
        >
           <TextView 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:id="@+id/tvDisclaimer">
           </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
         <LinearLayout      android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/svDisclaimer"
               >
      .. [ snip ] ..
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

( .. [snip] .. is where my buttons are)
The header is there, the scrollview pops up, but the buttons are nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ScrollView's height is set to `fill_parent` which pushes everything below the ScrollView off the bottom of the screen. You will never see what you cannot scroll to... try this pattern instead:

```
<ScrollView >
    <RelativeLayout >
        <TextView />
        <LinearLayout >
            <!-- [ snip ] -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can probably remove the LinearLayout by using the RelativeLayout position tags as well. (`android:below`, `android:toRightOf`, etc)

---

Try using this configuration from my comment:

```
<ScrollView
    ...
    android:above="@+id/buttons" >

    ...
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ... >

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The .. [snip] ..  is my two buttons. I want them always on the screen, so *outside* of the scrollview. I tried making the height of the scrollview wrap_content, to no avail.

Comment: Ok, use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` with your Buttons to anchor them to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Tried putting it in the `LinearLayout`. No effect.

Comment: About your last remark: adding the `layout_above` makes the app crash with a IllegalStateException in the Choregrapher (whatever that may be)

Comment: I seem to get it. Having both `layout_below` and `layout_above` will create a crash. Weird though that the one works, and the other doesn't. Apparantly it has something to do with the `height` set to `fill_parent`. It will be a nice day when I understand Android layouts :). Thanks for you help!

Comment: Sorry I removed the `below` attribute in my head, but I didn't explicitly tell you to remove it. Using both `above` and `below` creates circular logic for Android... Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Like Sam said, setting the ScrollView's height to fill_parent pushes the buttons off the screen. There's a way to make it work using the layout tags for RelativeLayout, though. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout>
[snip]
    <RelativeLayout>
         <!-- Declare the buttons *before* the ScrollView, but use layout params to move
         them to the bottom of the screen -->
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonParent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
              [Buttons go here]
         </LinearLayout>
         <!-- The "android:layout_above" attribute forces the ScrollView to leave space for the buttons -->
         <ScrollView
           android:height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_above="@id/buttonParent" />
             [snip]
         </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to put your top and bottom elements that must stay on the screen in framelayouts. http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2011/06/example-of-framelayout.html